# Remove Some Pages When User Press Back Button

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I am going from Component A -> Component B-> Component C ->Component D, now when user press back ,then I have to remove Component B and Component C from the stack and user have to land Component A.

What I am Currently doing to navigate from each component is this:
Component A -> Component B

```
this.props.history.push({
              pathname: config.URL_COMPONENT_B,
            })
```

Component B -> Component C

```
this.props.history.push({
              pathname: config.URL_COMPONENT_C,
            })
```

Component C -> Component D

```
 this.props.history.push({
              pathname: config.URL_COMPONENT_D,
            })
```

Now When user press back then , I am navigating back to  Component D -> Component C-> Component B ->Component A

I know it's the usual behaviour !!

Then what i tried when user go from Component C to COmponent D then ,I tried to use

```
 this.props.history.replace({
              pathname: config.URL_COMPONENT_D,
            })
```

But also it's not worked !! Any Suggestion

Comment: what do you mean "it's not worked" ?

Comment: @RedBaron   can't able yo move to Component A ,when i press back button from Component D

Comment: what happened tho?